# Use external DVD player with computer to play movies

Tags: video, hdmi, blu-ray, multimedia

I have a Sony BDP-S5200 Blu Ray player. It works fine with TVs, but I would like to connect it to my computer and watch movies using my computer monitor and speakers. Is that possible?

The player has an HDMI output. The player also has a digital coaxial audio output.

My computer has Firewire and USB inputs. My video card is an nVidia GeForce 9800 GTX+. I use the sound built in to my motherboard.

I assume that at a minimum I will have to buy a special card which accepts an HDMI input and then sends the video to the video card and the sound to the sound channel on the PC. Does such a card exist?

Alternatively I could plug the player directly into the monitor and then somehow try to get the sound from the coaxial out on the player, but a problem is that my motherboard seems to only have an SPDIF out, not an SPDIF input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your blueray player is likely using HDCP. To attach the blueray player to your computer you would have to find a capture card that supports HDCP. To the best of my knowledge such a device does not exist.

It is my understanding that Monitors with HDMI ports are HDCP compliant. Therefore you can hook the blue-ray player up to the monitor. However as you mentioned you have the issue of sound. If the monitor has built-in speakers or audio out, you'll are good to go.

An Audio Converter such as the [Orei DA21](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008EPW7TA) (Optical SPDIF/Coaxial Digital to RCA L/R Analog Audio Converter) would allow you to convert the Digital Coaxial connection to RCA Analog. Note the Orei DA21 was the first device that appeared after a quick google search and is used simply for an example.

A brief description from [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00021917/22085/MJ17ASKB) on what HDCP is all about.

> LCD: What Is High-Bandwidth Digital Content Protection System (HDCP)?
>
> HDCP (High-Bandwidth Digital Content Protection) is a specification
>   developed by Intel Corporation to protect digital content passed
>   between DVI (Digital Video Interface) compliant video transmitters
>   (computers, for example) and DVI compliant video receivers (monitors,
>   televisions, etc.).  In the past three years, the HDCP specification
>   has been extended to HDMI compliant equipment such as TVs.
>
> Before transmitting digital content, the transmitter transmits special
>   HDCP device keys to the video receiver which only accepts content if
>   it receives the correct keys. After the receiver has received the
>   device keys, the transmitter and receiver generate another value that
>   is transmitted and constantly checked as the digital content is
>   transmitted to verify the transmission. To further protect the
>   transmission, the transmitter encrypts the data before it sends it.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer monitor has HDMI input, just connect your DVD player to the monitor.

Comment: This would be great for silent movies.  What about the sound?

Comment: Check if The monitor had audio output and connect it to active speakers.